# Bootstrap-table filter extension populates <select> with complete list of html options

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Someone asked that question earlier, but I have a problem with HTML.

Bootstrap filter populates select element with HTML data instead of values.
I have only two options for Status: Active and Inactive, but filter takes Status of each row and puts inside select element.

[image: See this picture. It doesn't define data]

```
<table class="table sortable-theme-bootstrap table-hover"
       id="trucklist"
       data-escape="false"
       data-filter-control="true"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-search="true"
       data-page-size="25"
       data-show-columns="true"
       data-cookie="true"
       data-cookie-id-table="saveId">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="truck">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TruckNo)
            </th>
            <th data-sortable="false"
                data-field="fleet"
                data-filter-control="select">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FleetName)
            </th>
            <th data-field="lastDate"
                data-searchable="false"
                data-sortable="true"
                data-sorter="dateSorter">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastDate)
            </th>
            <th data-field="dispatch"
                data-filter-control="select"
                data-sortable="false">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DispatchName)
            </th>
            <th data-field="phone"
                data-searchable="false"
                data-sortable="false">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DispatchTelephone)
            </th>
            <th data-field="status"
                data-sortable="false"
                data-filter-control="select">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TruckStatus)
            </th>
            <th data-field="available"
                data-sortable="false"
                data-filter-control="select"
                data-filter-custom-search="data">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Availability.StatusText)
            </th>
            <th data-field="city"
                data-sortable="true"
                data-searchable="false">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Availability.AvailableCity)
            </th>
            <th data-field="from"
                data-sortable="true"
                data-searchable="false"
                data-sorter="dateSorter">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Availability.AvailableFrom)
            </th>
            <th data-sortable="false"
                data-searchable="false">
                Action
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TruckNo)
                </td>
                <td class="center">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FleetName)
                </td>
                <td class="center">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DispatchName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DispatchTelephone)
                </td>
                <td class="center">
                    <span class='label label-@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TruckStatusClass)'>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TruckStatusText)</span>
                </td>
                <td class="center">
                    <span class='label label-@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Availability.StatusClass)'>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Availability.StatusText)</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Availability.AvailableCity)
                </td>
                <td class="center">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Availability.AvailableFromDisplay)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { TruckID = item.TruckID }, new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-xs" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It works incorrectly only for these two:

```
 <td class="center">
                <span class='label label-@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TruckStatusClass)'>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TruckStatusText)</span>
            </td>
            <td class="center">
                <span class='label label-@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Availability.StatusClass)'>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Availability.StatusText)</span>
            </td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this by using bootstrap-table `data-filter-data-collector` attribute in the columns. For instance I've fixed this with creating this javascript function

```
window.tableFilterStripHtml = function (value) {
   return value.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '').trim();
}
```

and then in the column specifying the function like this:

```
<th data-field="state" data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="select" data-filter-data-collector="tableFilterStripHtml">State</th>
```

What this does is to call this function that ignores all HTML tags and returns a clean name of the filter. Since the HTML tags are those who create this issue to start with.

*I used quite a while to figure out how to fix it myself, so thought it's worth bumping this question for whoever who find themselves in the same issue.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the regex, that saved me a lot of time which you obviously spent for me :-)